# Swift JSON Saving issue

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

Using the Master/Detail Core Data template I am running into a strange issue but imagine it is just me being in over my head. When parsing a JSON file containing roughly 800 students the items are almost instantly added to the TableView which is fine. The issue I am having is when trying to save them to the Core Data context the app seems to pause for close to a minute.

```
@IBAction func loadStudents(sender: AnyObject) {

    var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let urlPath = NSURL(string: "**URL REMOVED**")
    let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = sharedSession.dataTaskWithURL(urlPath!, completionHandler: { (data, response, downloadTaskError) -> Void in

        println("Download Complete")

        if (downloadTaskError != nil) {

            println("Download Error: \(downloadTaskError!.localizedDescription)")

        } else {

            var studentJSONParseError: NSError?
            var studentJSONData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &studentJSONParseError) as NSArray

            if (studentJSONParseError != nil) {

                println("JSON Parsing Error: \(studentJSONParseError!.localizedDescription)")

            } else {

                for var i = 0; i < studentJSONData.count; i++ {

                    var student = studentJSONData[i] as NSDictionary
                    println("\(i) \(student)")
                    var newStudent = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Student", inManagedObjectContext: context) as Student
                    newStudent.firstName = student["STUDENT_FIRSTNAME"] as NSString
                    newStudent.lastName = student["STUDENT_SURNAME"] as NSString
                    newStudent.usualName = student["STUDENT_USUAL"] as NSString
                    newStudent.grade = student["STUDENT_GRADE"] as NSNumber
                    newStudent.id = student["STUDENT_ID"] as NSString
                    context.save(nil)

                }
            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are doing 800 saves. Try doing them outside the loop, or better even, do them app. 2 times every 400 records.

Second, your core data save happens on a different thread. Consider saving on the main thread where your fetched results controller lives. Background threads are good for saving large quantities of data, which does not seem to be the case here.